# Querying by a array column from a CTE

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I have a CTE with an array column and want to filter another column by that array of ids.

```
with vars as (
  select
    (1, 7, 10000) bubble_ids,
    'Frank' name
)

select * from walruses
inner join tusks on walruses.id = tusks.walrus_id
where (
  name = (select name from vars)
  and tusks.bubble_id IN (select bubble_ids from vars)
);
```

This produces the following: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = record`

I've tried unnesting—`unnest(bubble_ids)`—and this results in `ERROR:  record type has not been registered`

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1, 7, 10000)` does not define an array. That's a [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) which creates an anonymous record (with three fields).

An [array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) is written with square brackets and has to be prefixed with the keyword `array`, e.g. `array[1, 7, 10000]`. Alternatively you can write it as a string value: `'{1,7,1000}'`

When using a CTE as a "container" for variables/parameters, I usually use a cross join to make it accessible to the query. That is less typing

```
with vars as (
  select
    array[1, 7, 10000] bubble_ids,
    'Frank' as name --<< you need the AS, because name is a keywod
)
select * 
from walruses
  inner join tusks on walruses.id = tusks.walrus_id
  cross join vars v
where name = v.vars
  and tusks.bubble_id = any(v.bubble_ids);
```

---

I prefer the `values` clause over a `select` to define constant values.

```
with vars(bubble_ids, name) as (
  values (array[1, 7, 10000], 'Frank')
)
select * 
from walruses
  inner join tusks on walruses.id = tusks.walrus_id
  cross join vars v
where name = v.vars
  and tusks.bubble_id = any(v.bubble_ids);
```